# What is causing dark spots on my blueberry plant's leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, blueberries

This is my first year gardening and it is quite exciting watching my plants grow overtime. My question is that my blueberry plants have these dark spots on their leaves.

Any idea what they are or what I should do?

[image: Blueberry plant]